# Traceless nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A traceless, nilpotent $2 \times 2$ matrix with one real variable is already known. Does anyone know of a  $3 \times 3$ one, containing at least one real variable or parameter?

A nice set of properties is expected. If $M$ is such matrix, then $MM=0$,
$MM(t)+M(t)M=I$ where $M(t)$ is the transpose, $MM(t)$ and $M(t)M$ are Hermetian, and projector operators. $(PP=P)$

Comment: Surely nilpotent implies trace = $0$.  Does "traceless" mean something other than that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such matrix $M$, let alone a satisfactory parameterization.

In particular, if $M$ is $3\times 3$ with $M^2 = 0$, then 
$\operatorname{rank}(M) = 1$. So, we have 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(M^TM) = 
\operatorname{rank}(MM^T) = 1
$$
it follows that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(
M^TM + MM^T
) \leq 2 < 3 = \operatorname{rank}(I)
$$
so, it is impossible to have $M^TM + MM^T = I$.